# line of error appears when passing a message in php

Tags: php

i been working in the login code .. it works fine except this message that appears when openenig the login page !!

```
Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\thesite\login.php on line 103
```

it has appeard when i typed this  in loginExcution.php

```
    else {
        //Login failed
        header("location:login.php? msg=*invalid name or password");
        exit();
    }
```

and  this to show the message in the login form page

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
print $msg;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put spaces in your `header("Location:`.

```
else {
    //Login failed
    header("Location: login.php?msg=invalid%20name%20or%20password");
    exit();
}
```

**EDIT:** The `%20`s are actually spaces. Look at the PHP function `urlencode()` if you want more info. The code above is equivalent to this:

```
else {
    //Login failed
    header("Location: login.php?msg=" . urlencode("invalid name or password"));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You should also mention `urlencode()`, as it's neccessary and you applied it.

Comment: @Maerlyn done, thanks for pointing that out. It's been ages since i've dealt with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

beside removing first space mentioned in simplyianm answer.   if the code reaches this line $_GET['msg'] and msg is not defined index, it will trigger the notice.  you can do this instead

```
 if (isset($_GET['msg'])){
      $msg=$_GET['msg'];
      print $msg;
 }
```

though, passing the message content through the url is not a good idea. users can pass some javascript and send the link to unsuspecting user.   Instead you could make it a code  login.php?msg=invalid

then in the code

```
 if (isset($_GET['msg'])){
      switch ($msg){
          case "invalid":
              echo "Invalid username or password";
          break;
      }  
 }
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH it is working now i did it like this      if (isset  ($_GET['msg'])){ 
     
              echo "Invalid username or password";    
    }          i removed the switch case